# Fastening ceiling box to side of joist

Tags: electrical, joists, junction-box

Is there such a ceiling junction box that will allow me to attach it to the side of a joist from inside the box?

NB: I have a finished ceiling.

I know I can install a support bar and attach a box to it, but in a finished ceiling this can be a bit of a hassle.

I'm looking for a box that will allow me to put it into place and run the fasteners through the wall of the box and into the joist.  Maybe something that uses one of the side knockouts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a box available that has holes in the side so you can fasten it to a joist from the side.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can work with the octagon box and support bar, it's just that getting that support bar fastened to the joists from within a small hole (the diameter of the box) seems like a headache.  A palm air nailer might be in my future.

Comment: @Mike  I just edited my answer for a side mount. hope this helps.

Comment: Wait, am I allowed to use those holes to nail/screw through?  I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: @Mike Yes, not only is that what they're for, they're not for anything else.   If you don't like their position, feel free to drill others.  Except the one tapped #10-32 for a ground screw, but Murphy's Law says everytime you go to attach the ground, you discover you already used that hole for a mounting screw!

Comment: Funny how I've dealt with a bunch of junction boxes lately (not just in the garage), seen those holes, and never thought they might have a use.  My eyes have been opened!

Comment: @Mike ... Just woke up... Yes you can use them, but you already knew that thanks to "THE MAN". I usually  use screws because nailing in at the angle just never works for me